# Preload/Globally certain classes in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I Have got some models (mapped on database tables), in a python project. I want to make them preload when the project bootup so i don't need to do like this in every file

`from db.models.user import User`

I tried to load them in **init**.py file, but they are not available.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** You need to import your models in every file.

---

In Python, every module (`*.py` file) has its own namespace (set of global variables).  There is no way to have a *truly* global variable (or class, function, etc.), because every name is local to the module in which it is defined.  This is a deliberate feature of Python; it would be very bad if (for example) you could redefine the `range()` function in some random module and break everyone else's code.

You can place the import `from db.models.user import User` in `db/models/__init__.py`, but that won't make `User` globally accessible.  Instead, it will create an alias `db.models.User` for the original class (`db.models.user.User`), which you still have to import as normal.  This may save you a small amount of typing when importing the model in other places, and is a great way to flatten deep hierarchies of packages, but it does not make anything truly global, because you cannot make things global.